# Programmable thermostat not working

Tags: electrical

My Honeywell programmable thermostat is not turning on my furnace when I turn up the heat.

I put the wires in their places y=yellow and r=red as per the label inside the housing.

[image: thermostat in question]

Comment: Did you take a picture of the old thermostat or how it was wired?  Y is actually a call for cooling in the modern color code, but wires don't know what they're for based on the color of the insulation.  Pictures of the wiring at the furnace control board will tell what that yellow wire is connected to.

Answer (score 6):

The wire's color is *supposed to be* white -- perhaps it's aged or the lighting is poor.

When there are two conductors and it's a heat-only system, one of them goes to R and the other goes to W.

Comment: Greg , you’re a smart man. It worked , thank you

Comment: As per [site guidelines](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Also, "thank you" comments are expressly prohibited.